# How do I setup XAMPP server with my registered domain?

Tags: server, xampp, web, web-hosting, domain-name

When I buy a domain (ex. website.com) and setup my XAMPP or WAMP server, what should I do to show files from my XAMPP / WAMP server when someone types my domin name to te browser? I know that I should type something to httpacess file (found it here on stackoverflow), but is it that easy? 
What if someone else set up my domain with his server before I do?
Thanks!
I mean, what is the process from buying domain and starting Xampp or Wamp to make my webfiles show when the domain is typed in browser url box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know the fixed ip address for this.

If you know the fixed ip address, you need to create a nameserver for the domain and direct these nameservers to the ip address.

Then you should direct the domain to these nameservers. Domainin will be directed.